# Cross Compiling v4l2-ctl for Android

Tags: android, makefile, v4l2

I've got a usb camera working on android (via Android On-The-Go), and I'm looking to change the exposure of the camera. I've been able to get this to work by using v4l2-ctl on a linux machine, and I'm hoping to do the same on my Android device.

The install file mentions the following:

```
Android Cross Compiling and Installing:
----------------

v4l-utils will only build using the complete AOSP source tree, because of the
stlport dependency.

List of v4l-utils that supply an Android.mk makefile:
* utils/v4l2-compliance
* utils/v4l2-ctl
* utils/v4l2-dbg

To cross compile an utility you must first configure the shell with Android's
envsetup.sh to add the mm alias, before running lunch to select your target
device.

cd /path/to/aosp
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch
cd /path/to/v4l-utils
cd <utility>
mm
```

So I downloaded the android source, ran the first two commands and `lunch` successfully. I then `cd'd` into `v4l-utils/v4l2-ctl` and ran `mm`. I got the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o', needed by `out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/v4l2-ctl_intermediates/LINKED/v4l2-ctl'.  Stop.
```

What can I try to fix this?

*Note: Normal compilation works: I can make all of v4l2 with `./bootstrap.sh`, `./configure`, and then `make`.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it! I found that the instructions worked great, except for these two points:

## Download and Build the Entire Android Source

- Before doing anything, you need to download and make the full Android source. This means [setting up your environment](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html), [downloading it](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), and then [building it](https://source.android.com/source/building.html).
- Make sure that you're downloading the correct version of the Android source (that is, the version that's running on your phone).
- For a faster download, run `repo-sync` with `-c`, for the current branch only
- I suggest getting a large hourly billed server and running it on there. The network connection will be better, and the machine is probably better than your own. I got an 8 core, 16GB machine on DigitalOcean.
- When running `lunch`, I just chose the first option: `aosp_arm-eng`

## Set the TOP Variable

- When doing the `mm` step, you'll get an error saying `Couldn't locate the top of the tree.  Try setting TOP.` So run `export TOP=/location/of/android/source`